# Can $\frac{1}{2}(2x-6)\ln(2x-6)-\frac{1}{2}(2x-6)$ simplify to $(x-3)(\ln(2x-6)-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{1}{2}(2x-6)\ln(2x-6)-\frac{1}{2}(2x-6)$$

Can the above expression be simplified in the fallowing way?

$$(x-3)\ln(2x-6)-(x-3)$$

then to

$$(x-3)(\ln(2x-6)-1)$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Try using the distributive property to reduce $\frac{1}{2}(2x-6)$.

Comment: Thank you. Wolfram was suggesting $-x+(x-3) log(2 (x-3))+3$ which I did not believe to be as attractive.

Answer (score 0):

not that $$\frac{1}{2}(2x-6)=x-3$$ thus we have $$(x-3)\ln(2x-6)-(x-3)=(x-3)\left(\ln(2x-6)-1\right)$$

Comment: Is "not" suppose to be "note" ?